# Nashorn Script Engine is null on Java 8 SE Embedded

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I am attempting to bring JavaScript funtionality onto my robotics platform, usijng Java 8's brand new Nashorn engine. Here's the line used to create an instance of the Nashorn script engine:

```
ScriptEngine nashorn = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

Running this on my own computer works fine, but on the deployment platform, the resulting nashorn object is null, and whenever it is used of course gives a NullPointerException. After a little debugging, we know that the new ScriptEngineManager() is not null, however the engine returned by .getEngineByName(); is null.

This issue is occuring on the FIRST Robotics roboRIO, running Java 8 SE Embedded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using [compact 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/tech/compact-profiles-overview-2157132.html) Java profile for creating JRE. You should create Your own JRE which includes nashorn.

Comment: Though it's not supported, it should be possible to copy (from SE) a version of nashorn.jar into the lib/ext/ directory on the embedded device.

Answer (score 0):

nashorn is supported in SE Embedded.

You can either copy the nashorn.jar from the SE Embedded ejdk1.8.0 binaries
to your jre/lib/ext directory or run the jrecreate.sh tool included in the
Embedded JDK (ejdk1.8.0).

Here's the most recent SE embedded downloads:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/index.html

Here's an example of how to use jrecreate:

cd ejdk1.8.0_xx/bin
sh jrecreate --profile compact2 -x nashorn --dest {target JRE directory}

In case FIRST Robotics included other embedded extensions, you can look at
the "bom" file at the top of the JRE you are currently running.  This contains the jrecreate command that was used to generate your JRE.

Bob Vandette
Java SE Embedded Lead
Oracle